# Can not redirect to action on MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a View to update Order with some fields and two buttons (Submit button and  Back button)

i use jquery ajax to send parameters from View to controller:

```
function onUpdate(e) {
    var data = getParameters()
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateOrder", "Home")',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function () {
        }
    });
};
```

And my controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult UpdateOrder(int orderId,int provinceId,int paymentType,int totalAmount,string isClosed)
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.OrderId = orderId;
        order.ProvinceId = provinceId;
        order.PaymentTypeId = paymentType;
        order.TotalAmount = totalAmount;
        order.IsClosed = isClosed=="True"?true:false;
        order.UpdateOrder(order);
        return RedirectToAction("Default");       
    }
```

when i click submit, record updated, but not redirect to default action.

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page. You may as well just use a standard submit if you want to redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of redirecting from httppost controller try this :-

```
function onUpdate(e) {
    var data = getParameters()
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateOrder", "Home")',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function () {
         window.location.href="/yourcontroller/Default"; //<------redirect here
        }
    });
};

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult UpdateOrder(int orderId,int provinceId,int paymentType,int totalAmount,string isClosed)
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.OrderId = orderId;
        order.ProvinceId = provinceId;
        order.PaymentTypeId = paymentType;
        order.TotalAmount = totalAmount;
        order.IsClosed = isClosed=="True"?true:false;
        order.UpdateOrder(order);
        return Json(new{}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //  <------ change here       
    }
```

Or just instead of invoking a HttpPost controller from jquery ajax you can perform a normal post with form submit,with normal post you can redirect wherever you want.

Comment: Thank so much, it working nice. But i must waiting 7 minutes more to mark your answer

Comment: b/c i use Kendo UI, some controls binding by ajax, so when i use normal post with form submit, i can't receiver values from controls

Comment: i just try return Json(null) and Json(new{}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); Two ways working the same. Have any diffirences between two ways?

Comment: @NguyễnHuy..yes..sometimes json(null) creates problems with older jquery version like 1.6.x or 1.7.1 so its good to use json(new{})